# Circle set and get

Tags: c#, linq, get, set

I have the working code, the set and get are supposed to not allow negative input. However, when this is run, negative input still returns results, what am I missing that is causing the negative values to still be calculated? Also, how would I introduce a function that allow the user to calculate for more than one circle?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace console
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("What is the circle’s radius: ");
            double radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Circle ans = new Circle(radius);


            Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is " + ans.getArea);
            Console.WriteLine("The Diameter of the circle is " + ans.getDiameter);
            Console.WriteLine("The Circumference of the circle is " + ans.getCircumference);

            Console.Write("Enter any character to quit program. ");
            double stop = Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

That's the method and the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace console
{
    class Circle
    {

        public double radius;
        public const double PI = 3.14159;

        public Circle(double r)
        {
            radius = r;
        }

        public Circle()
        {
            radius = 0.0;
        }

        public double getDiameter
        {
            get
            {
                return radius * 2;
            }

        }


        public double getArea
        {
            get
            {
                return PI * radius * radius;
            }

        }
        public double getCircumference
        {
            get
            {
                return 2 * PI * radius;
            }

        }
        // property Radius 
        public double Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return radius;
            }

            set
            {
                // ensure non-negative radius value 
                if (value >= 0)
                    radius = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are changing value of your `public` field not the `property` so your `setter` method is never executed.I think you should make your field `private`, then change your constructor like this:

```
private double radius;
public Circle(double r)
{
    Radius = r;
}
```

Also you might want to display a message or throw an exception in your setter method when the user try to assign negative value to `radius`.

> Also, how would I introduce a function that allow the user to calculate for more than one circle?

You can use a `loop` for that.Put your code inside of a loop and declare a counter.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    /* put your code here, get the input perform the calculation
     and display the message */
}
```

Another way might be usin a `while` loop:

```
while(true)
{
    /* put your code here */

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to continue ? (y/n)");
    var userChoice = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    if(char.ToLower(userChoice) != 'y') break;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Now how would I go about asking if user wants to do another circle or if a letter is entered it returns to the beginning of the program? I know this would be done through the main method though from there I am lost.

Comment: I tried your suggestion for the loop, is there anyway that instead of having a set number of trials, the user defines when they stop perhaps through a y/n? y indicating continuation and n stopping the program?

Comment: @user3429402 so you got your idea, why don't you try it ?